# F# Giving a function parameters or not - what's the difference

Tags: f#

I have a couple of functions for doing basic arithmetic on polynomials. Initially, I defined the functions without explicitly providing parameters, but when it came to using some of these functions inside another function, things started coming apart, until I changed them to take parameters.

The code is better at explaining it:

```
//Multiplying a polynomial with a constant
let rec mulC = function
| (_,[])                    -> []
| (x,y::tail) when x > 0    -> x * y::mulC(x,tail)

//Adding two polynomials
let rec addE = function
| ([],[])                   -> []
| ([], y::ytail)            -> y::ytail
| (x::xtail,[])             -> x::xtail
| (x::xtail, y::ytail)      -> (x + y) :: addE(xtail,ytail)

//Multiplying a polynomial by x
let mulX = function
| []                    -> []
| xs                    -> 0::xs

//Multiplying two polynomials
let rec mul = function
| []                    -> []
| x::tail               -> addE (mulC x qs)
                                (mulX(mul qs tail))
```

Now, this gives an error This value is not a function and cannot be applied at addE in the function mul at the very end.

If I change the function definitions to this though, it works:

```
let rec mulC x ys =
match (x,ys) with
| (_,[])                    -> []
| (x,y::ys) when x > 0    -> x * y::mulC x ys

let rec addE xs ys =
match (xs, ys) with
| ([],[])                   -> []
| ([], y::ys)            -> y::ys
| (x::xs,[])             -> x::xs
| (x::xs, y::ys)      -> (x + y) :: addE xs ys

let mulX xs = 
match xs with
| []                    -> []
| xs                    -> 0::xs

let rec mul qs = function
| []                    -> []
| x::tail               -> addE (mulC x qs)
                                (mulX(mul qs tail))
```

What gives?

Comment: First definitions expect one 2-tuple as parameter not 2 separate parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `function` keyword creates a function that takes **one** parameter and goes straight into a pattern match on it. These three functions are all equivalent and have a type signature of `(int * int) -> int`. There is a single 2-tuple parameter:

```
let add = function (a, b) -> a + b
let add' = fun x -> match x with (a, b) -> a + b
let add'' x = match x with (a, b) -> a + b
```

Whereas this function has a type signature of `int -> int -> int`. There are 2 parameters:

```
let add a b = a + b
```

---

But why did you get the error `This value is not a function and cannot be applied.`? Because `addE` takes one argument and returns a `list`. You applied one argument so the type system infers that you have a list, and then tried to apply another argument to that list, but list is not a function. You can get the same error with just this code:

```
[] 1
```